# Failure installing python module

Tags: python, ssl, pip, pycharm, tls1.2

I get this message when ever I try to install pysimplegui from pycharm

Collecting PySimpleGUI
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pysimplegui/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pysimplegui/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pysimplegui/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pysimplegui/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pysimplegui/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pysimplegui/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pysimplegui/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PySimpleGUI (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PySimpleGUI
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

Any ideas how I can get around this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet connection first and retry again.If this does not work, follow these simple steps to install it.

Open your terminal and go to the file path or project path
(If you are using virtual environment, activate the virtual environment) 
Now do "pip3 install PySimpleGUI"

this worked for me